# Indexing structure for all-pairs min-cuts in a huge DAG

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, directed-acyclic-graph, max-flow-min-cut

I have a huge DAG - e.g., the dependency graph of all packages in a linux distribution.

Suppose I'd like to make a user-friendly tool that makes it very easy to understand how to break the transitive dependency between package A and package B, and do other related queries/algorithms.

The question "how to break a transitive dependency" is answered by a min-cut.

Is there a practical indexing structure for answering all-pairs min-cut that works for large DAGs (non-ridiculous time and space complexity)? I am aware of Gomory-Hu trees (though I have not yet grasped them), but they seem to work only for undirected graphs.

Comment: Do you only care about the $s-t$-min cut value or do you also want to have a min-cut for each $s-t$?

Comment: @ChaoXu apparently the values only.

Comment: I would like the actual cuts, but values would be interesting too.